# Flutter: Validate only one TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I am building a User Registration form with Flutter. I need to achieve the following :-

1. Require user to enter their preferred **User ID**
2. Add a button at the end of **TextFormField** so that user can validate if that **User ID** had been taken or not.
3. When that button is clicked, it will call the validator function to validate only the **User ID** (not any other field within the form)
4. Regardless of whether the use click the validate button, the **User ID** will still be validated when the form is submitted.

I have tried numerous ways, and it seems like the only solution is to split the User ID with all other forms into a separate form.

May I know if there is a better solution than this?

Comment: call `FormFieldState.validate()` method (or use `isValid` property)

Comment: @pskink, I almost got it working. Except the error message is not showing correctly. Can you please help?

Comment: @pksink, thanks I have it working now. Seems like my original design is too complicated. Will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `GlobalKey`

```
var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

2. Add the `_formKey` to, your `TextFormField`, The Form Widget should add to only to that field which you want to Validate.

```
Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 10.0),
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: TextFormField(
      maxLines: 1,
      style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none, color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 14.0, fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, letterSpacing: 0.0,),
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Type here...', alignLabelWithHint: true, border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),)),
      validator: (_post) => _post.toString().trim().length == 0 ? "Empty text" : null,
      onSaved: (_post) => _postText = _post.toString().trim(),
    ),
  ),
)
```

3. Then OnClick of any Button call the Validate function.

```
void _validateInputs() {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
       // Call your Method
    }
  }
```